# Django Snippets/Updating Primary Key

Tags: mysql, django, orm

I have a client that requested (after launch) to start their records at a very large number (3,000,000).

The model itself has at least 10 relationships/reverse relationships all through FK, established with "on_delete=CASCADE". Originally I was working with this snippet: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10619/, which gave quite a few errors.

After some formatting (removing %s formatting for easier to read f-string formatting), the script ran but gave the dreaded: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails.

I am looking at any sort of way to get the 100 or so records (and their respective relationships) to update accordingly.

I have already updated the MYSQL database to start numbering from the last record + 3,000,000 so that any resulting scripts should not result in a collision keeping the PK restraints.

I believe there used to be a way to do this via a simple model.objects.all().update(id=F('id')+3000000), but this also has failed in Django 4.2.

Any help is appreciated. d

Comment: Are records already created in production?

Comment: You said after launch. What is the current state of the app? is it still pre-launch? post-launch? If pre-launch you can re-migrate with starting key to 3,000,000.

Comment: You have to disable FK checks before changing FKs or you have to first detack the child rows by setting their FK to null while preserving somewhere else their relatuonships, update the parent it amd then set the child FK to the new parent id.

Comment: Please *don't* alter primary keys. You should see primary keys as black box identifiers where the fact that these are integers is an implementation detail.

Comment: Post production, records already created.  I know generally this isn't standard.  Django used to cascade update fk/pk changes with . Update but I think this was removed in Django 4.    I have already ran the alter table command in mysql to begin numbering higher, and left space to move the records.  Not a deal breaker with the client but nice to have.